# How to remove code duplication in template

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have the following XSLT templates

```
<xsl:template match="body/table/rows">
      <fo:table-row font-weight="bold">
         <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
               <xsl:value-of select="date" />
            </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
      ..............
      </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body/table/result">
      <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
               <xsl:value-of select="date" />
            </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
      ..............
      </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
```

the difference in the templates is that for the element `<fo:table-row>` there is `font-weight="bold"` and the other one doesn't have, however the content of both templates which is made of `<fo:table-cell` is the same,clearly this is a code duplication. Is there a way to remove this code duplication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <xsl:template match="body/table/rows | body/table/result">
      <fo:table-row>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="font-weight"/>
         <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
               <xsl:value-of select="date" />
            </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
      ..............
      </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body/table/rows" mode="font-weight">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="font-weight"/>
```

Comment: Nice solution, I was wondering is there also a way to set in a variable "body/table" because it looks like a dublication?

Comment: XSLT 3.0 allows the pattern `match="body/table/(rows|result)"` but since you didn't say what version you were using, I wrote it in a way that works with all versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a mode:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="cell">
         <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
               <xsl:value-of select="date" />
            </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
</xsl:template>
```

and apply-templates where you had the `fo:table-cell` elements, i.e. use `<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="cell"/>`.

You could also think about parameterizing the template and including the `fo:table-row` with the font weight as a parameter.

Comment: Or use `<xsl:template name="cell">` and have the templates for `rows` and `result` each use `<xsl:call-template name="cell" />`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the simplest solution in your case would be to add the attribute conditionally:

```
<xsl:template match="rows | result">
    <fo:table-row>
        <xsl:if test="self::rows">
            <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="date" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <!--  .... -->
    </fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

A more generic solution would place the common code in a **named** template and **call** that template from both specific templates, or - in XSLT 2.0 and higher - use the [`xsl:next-match`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-next-match) instruction.

---

Untested because no input example was provided.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using at least XSLT 2.0...

```
<xsl:template match="body/table/result" name="row">
   <xsl:param name="atts" select="()" as="attribute()*" />

    <fo:table-row>
         <xsl:sequence select="$atts" />
         <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
               <xsl:value-of select="date" />
            </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
      ..............
      </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- A higher-priority template or a template in an importing
       stylesheet can use <xsl:next-match> and provide overriding
       attributes. -->
  <xsl:template match="body/table/rows">
    <xsl:param name="atts" select="()" as="attribute()*" />

    <xsl:call-template name="row">
      <xsl:with-param name="atts" as="attribute()*">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:sequence select="$atts" />
      </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Technique is used in successive variations for formatting 'Moby Dick': e.g., https://github.com/AntennaHouse/moby-dick/blob/af2c762dc60287d9accb8d9959b15c2c8444ee31/river.xsl#L169